# Do I need a specific Python module Oauthentication?

Tags: python, twitter, module

I checked the documentation for Python-Twitter and I couldn't find any methods for OAuthentication. There is a  methods for Basic Auth, but I obviously can't use that any more.

If I get a separate module for Oauth can I still use methods in Python-Twitter that require Oauth or does the Oauth only support methods from the same module I authenticated in.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is a generic protocol; any well-behaved library that implements it should work with any site's API (this is the whole point of having a standard...)

Answer (score 0):

Python-Twitter supports OAuth which is based on the [python-oauth2](http://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) according to the docs.